# Python inner container class

Tags: python, class, object, inner-classes

```
from itertools import count

class myobject(object):
    id=count(0)
    def __init__(self):
        self.ID=next(self.id)
        self.dat=[]

class bucket(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.container_object=self.Container_object
        class Container_object(object):
            self.container={}
            self.contained_objects=self.container.keys()
        def create_object(myobject):
            self.container[myobject.ID]=object_data
```

I am looking to create a container object within class bucket such that I can create different instances of myobject within class bucket.

Such that when create_object creates new object that can be accessed and contained within class bucket.Container_object  and **bucket.Container_object.ID would be an instance of myobject**

PS I am new to classes and still try to understand how I can use them, so most likely the question shows this understanding. Please feel free to point to those misunderstandings. thanks

Comment: Can you show (in code) how this is supposed to work, and also what's going wrong?

Comment: Also, class names should be `PascalCase`, per [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for.
A class Bucket which contains multiple **instances** of class MyObject. Since you don't specify any particular peculiarities of your Container object, I will use a simple dictionary.

```
from itertools import count

class MyObject(object):
    id=count(0)
    def __init__(self):
        self.ID=next(self.id)
        self.dat=[]

class Bucket(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.contained_objects={}

    def add_object(myobject):
        self.contained_objects[myobject.ID]=myobject.dat
```

If you want to wrap the collection inside some other object for some reasons, you simply define the WrapperContainer **class** outside the Bucket class and simply instantiate an **instance** of WrapperContainer inside it.

```
from itertools import count

class MyObject(object):
    id=count(0)
    def __init__(self):
        self.ID=next(self.id)
        self.dat=[]

class WrapperContainer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.collection = {}

    def add_object(my_object):
        self.collection[myobject.ID]=myobject.dat

    def do_whatever_you_want():
       pass


class Bucket(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.container_object= WrapperContainer() #a specific instance

    def add_object(myobject):
        self.container_object.add_object(my_object)
```

Finally, you can think at your container class as a subclass of an already existent collection (list or dictionary or anything else) to inherit its features.